# pop-global-mark won't jump to last location

Tags: emacs

For some reason C-x C-space doesn't work on my emacs. It just jumps to the beginning of the file instead of jumping to the last cursor position.

1. I tested this by typing a bunch of random characters across the page
2. I hit C-x C-space expecting it to jump back to each of those locations
3. instead all it does is jump to the top of the buffer

If I switch buffers, it does jump back to the first buffer but to the top of the buffer not to my last edit location. I tried using "M-x pop-global-mark" too but it does the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C-u C-SPC` (`set-mark-command`) cycles among marks on the mark ring, that is, markers in the current buffer.  You recipe does not set any markers.  Go to various places and hit `C-SPC` at them, to set the mark there.  Then you can use `C-U C-SPC` to cycle among them.

`C-x C-SPC` (`pop-global-mark`) cycles *global* marks, i.e., one mark in each buffer where you set the mark.

Comment: @stackOverlord Interesting question, please file it, not having an answer buried in comments.

Comment: And the answer is... See `highlight-changes-mode` and `global-highlight-changes-mode`.  `highlight-changes-next-change` moves to the next change etc.